# account recovery with web3 privateKeyToAccount()

Tags: web3js, metamask, private-key, ecdsa

I'm currently stucked by this strange thing: 
I started by exporting my private key(`fdba67e41f7c6767100969ae3f045d10a59e35d380acf5b37a3b208bd2969347`) from my **metamask account**, which i can use to login with MEW without problem (and gives me the address `0xa6CDA44CEA3Ac87435d9fDF548B051dDE90D128F`):

[image]

But when I use the function `web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount()` with this private key as input, it's not creating an account with the corresponding public key as address.

```
var account_1_priv = 'fdba67e41f7c6767100969ae3f045d10a59e35d380acf5b37a3b208bd2969347';

var acc = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(account_1_priv);
console.log(acc)

>>> { address: '0xaF6d10CbEcd036f713cA504d3e952F2A31845EB9',
privateKey:'fdba67e41f7c6767100969ae3f045d10a59e35d380acf5b37a3b208bd2969347',
signTransaction: [Function: signTransaction],
sign: [Function: sign],
encrypt: [Function: encrypt] }
```

The new address showned here became `0xaF6d10CbEcd036f713cA504d3e952F2A31845EB9`.

#### Same thing with the sign function

I need to sign a transaction locally with my private key `privKey`, and I used it in the following way: (last line with the `sign` function from web3.eth.accounts)

```
var account_1_priv = 'fdba67e41f7c6767100969ae3f045d10a59e35d380acf5b37a3b208bd2969347';
var hashdata = "0x2ff5a3650ca0391b59cf6614820cac78fd7564302c5614349990117b21df0eeb";

var result = web3.eth.accounts.sign(hashdata, account_1_priv)
console.log(result)

>> { message: '0x2ff5a3650ca0391b59cf6614820cac78fd7564302c5614349990117b21df0eeb',    
messageHash: '0x5c9aac8744ec24ede5fc8e3125cf4e388d14afb8e809575fdd9477ecee44db33',
v: '0x1b',
r: '0x93291c697b8e30350f93e7b13e27b6dd232d6d4d9cb5edb8a32c06554ed2bafd',
s: '0x79f2d63e1225f4f7d4f0caff85f5af39599b8630c81abd9b758ad1915b001b49',
signature: '0x93291c697b8e30350f93e7b13e27b6dd232d6d4d9cb5edb8a32c06554ed2bafd79f2d63e1225f4f7d4f0caff85f5af39599b8630c81abd9b758ad1915b001b491b' 
}
```

but later when I want to verify the public key with `hashdata`, `v`, `r`, `s` on solidity with `ercrecovery` like this:

```
  ecrecover(bytes32 hashdata, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s);
```

I got the output of `0xaF6d10CbEcd036f713cA504d3e952F2A31845EB9`, which is the same as the `privateKeyToAccount()` gave me, but different from my metamask account. Am I using any of these functions wrong? how can I sign the message correctly  with a private key on behavior of my metamask account? I was thinking about maybe the problem is related to the HD wallet structure, but haven't found any related topics yet.

Answer (score 4):

Use `0xfdba67e41f7c6767100969ae3f045d10a59e35d380acf5b37a3b208bd2969347` instead (with a `0x` prefix) so web3 knows the format of the private key:

```
web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount('0xfdba67e41f7c6767100969ae3f045d10a59e35d380acf5b37a3b208bd2969347').address
"0xa6CDA44CEA3Ac87435d9fDF548B051dDE90D128F"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use 0xfdba67e41f7c6767100969ae3f045d10a59e35d380acf5b37a3b208bd2969347 instead (with a 0x prefix) so web3 knows the format of the private key:

```
web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount('0xfdba67e41f7c6767100969ae3f045d10a59e35d380acf5b37a3b208bd2969347').address
```

"0xa6CDA44CEA3Ac87435d9fDF548B051dDE90D128F"